Using both Categorized and Graduated renderers simultaneously in QGIS
I am working on a map in QGIS 3.28 and would like to display two different types of information simultaneously using both the Categorized and Graduated renderers. Specifically, I want to categorize my data based on one attribute and, at the same time, graduate the symbols based on another attribute.
Is it possible to combine both renderers so that I can see both categories and graduated values on the same map layer?

You will need to use the categorized renderer first then use the data defined override assistant for symbol size : https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#data-defined-override-setup
